# Pagination works if I use an integer to specify the number of records to display per page; adding a dropdown makes you specify the number of records

Tags: php

When I set the following variable to an integer value, pagination display that number of records per page on current and subsequent pages.  If I set that variable to a variable that contains the number of records to display per page, the subsequent or previous page shows no records - until you select a number from the dropdown menu.

When the following is set, all pages show that same number of records per page:
`$perPageLimit = 5;`

If I change that to:
`$perPageLimit = $_REQUEST['npp'];`
any page but the current page displays NO records until you select a number from the dropdown.

```
**If a user selects 10 records to display, I want the code to keep that same number to display on all pages.  If a user selects 25 to display, all pages should display 25 records WITHOUT having to have the user specify the number of records per page.**

**This is my full code for this page:**
```

```
    <?php

// Start session
session_start();

include_once 'config/dbconfig.php';

}


// Get session data
$sessData = !empty($_SESSION['sessData'])?$_SESSION['sessData']:'';

// Load pagination class
require_once 'Pagination.class.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["username"]); ?>'s Leads | CRM</title>
    
</head>
<body class="a2z-wrapper" cz-shortcut-listen="true" style="width:90%;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;background-color:#9dc7f1;">

<?php
include './header2.php';

echo "
<form action=\"$targetpage\" method=POST>
<input type=hidden name=page value=\"$page\">
Show <select name=\"npp\">
<option selected>$limit</option>
<option value=5>5</option>
<option value=10>10</option>
<option value=25>25</option>
<option value=50>50</option>
</select>
<span>&nbsp;Leads</span>
<input type=submit value=\"Go\">
</form>
";

// Load and initialize database class
require_once 'DB.class.php';
$db = new DB();

// Page offset and limit
// $perPageLimit = 5;
$perPageLimit = $_REQUEST['npp'];
$offset = !empty($_GET['page'])?(($_GET['page']-1)*$perPageLimit):0;



// Get count of the prospects
$con = array(
    'like_or' => $searchArr,
    'return_type' => 'count'
);
$rowCount = $db->getRows('wpbestp_home_purchase', $con);


// Initialize pagination class
$pagConfig = array(
    'baseURL' => 'myleads2.php'.$searchStr,
    'totalRows' => $rowCount,
    'perPage' => $perPageLimit
);
$pagination = new Pagination($pagConfig);

// Get leads from database
$con = array(
    'like_or' => $searchArr,
    'start' => $offset,
    'limit' => $perPageLimit,
    'order_by' => 'id DESC',
);
$prospects = $db->getRows('wpbestp_home_purchase', $con);
    
    <!-- Data list table --> 
    <table cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="sortable" class="table table-striped table-hover table-responsive" style="margin-left:-30px;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th onclick="sortBy(0)">ID&nbsp;&#x2B0D;</th>
                <th onclick="sortBy(1)">Trans Type&nbsp;&#x2B0D;</th>
                <th onclick="sortBy(2)">Entered&nbsp;&#x2B0D;</th>
                <th onclick="sortBy(3)">FName&nbsp;&#x2B0D;</th>
                <th onclick="sortBy(4)">LName&nbsp;&#x2B0D;</th>
                <th onclick="sortBy(5)">Loan Amount&nbsp;&#x2B0D;</th>
                <th onclick="sortBy(6)">LTV&nbsp;&#x2B0D;</th>
                <th onclick="sortBy(7)">Email&nbsp;&#x2B0D;</th>
                <th onclick="sortBy(8)">Phone&nbsp;&#x2B0D;</th>
                <th onclick="sortBy(9)">Dup Phone&nbsp;&#x2B0D;</th>
                <th onclick="sortBy(10)">Prop Address&nbsp;&#x2B0D;</th>
                <th onclick="sortBy(11)">Prop City&nbsp;&#x2B0D;</th>
                <th onclick="sortBy(12)">Prop State&nbsp;&#x2B0D;</th>
                <th onclick="sortBy(13)">Prop Zip&nbsp;&#x2B0D;</th>
                <th onclick="sortBy(14)">Sales Price&nbsp;&#x2B0D;</th>
                <th onclick="sortBy(15)">Assigned&nbsp;&#x2B0D;</th>
                <th onclick="sortBy(16)">Prospect Msg&nbsp;&#x2B0D;</th>
                <th onclick="sortBy(17)">Status&nbsp;&#x2B0D;</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
            if(!empty($prospects)){ $count = 0; 
                foreach($prospects as $prospect){ $count++;
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $prospect['id']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $prospect['transaction_type']; ?></td>
                <td><?php 
                if ($prospect['time_ago_second'] > "0" AND $prospect['time_ago_second'] < "180") {
                    echo $prospect['time_ago_second'], " seconds ago";
                } else if ($prospect['time_ago_second'] > "180" AND $prospect['time_ago_second'] < "3600") {
                    echo $prospect['time_ago_minute'], " minutes ago";
                } else if ($prospect['time_ago_minute'] > "59" AND $prospect['time_ago_minute'] < "120") {
                    echo "Over ", $prospect['time_ago_hour'], " hour ago";
                } else if ($prospect['time_ago_minute'] > "120" AND $prospect['time_ago_minute'] < "1400") {
                    echo "Over ", $prospect['time_ago_hour'], " hours ago";
                } else if ($prospect['time_ago_hour'] > "24" AND $prospect['time_ago_hour'] < "48") {
                    echo "Over ", $prospect['time_ago_day'], " day ago";
                } else if ($prospect['time_ago_hour'] > "24") {
                    echo "Over ", $prospect['time_ago_day'], " days ago";
                } else ''
                ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $prospect['fName']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $prospect['lName']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo number_format($prospect['loan_amount']); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo number_format((float)($prospect[loan_amount]/$prospect[salesprice])*100,2,'.',''); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $prospect['pemail']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo '(' .substr($prospect['primary_phone'],0,3) . ') ' . substr($prospect['primary_phone'], 3,3) . '-' . substr($prospect['primary_phone'], 6,4); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $prospect['dupphonenum']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $prospect['property_street']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $prospect['property_city']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $prospect['property_state']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $prospect['property_zipcode']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $prospect['salesprice']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $prospect['assigned_to']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $prospect['user_message']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $prospect['lead_status']; ?></td>
                <td>
                    <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" style="font-size:1.4em;" href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $prospect['id']; ?>" id="cb" style="pointer-events: none;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit">                    
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php } }else{ ?>
            <tr><td colspan="5" style="font-size:1.4em;">No lead(s) found......</td></tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br>
    <!-- Display pagination links --> 
    <?php echo $pagination->createLinks(); ?>
</div>
```

```
**Here is the pagination file code:**
```

```
    <?php

class Pagination{
    protected $baseURL        = '';
    protected $totalRows      = '';
    protected $perPage        = 10;
    protected $numLinks       = 2;
    protected $currentPage    = 0; 
    protected $firstLink      = 'First';
    protected $nextLink       = 'NEXT';
    protected $prevLink       = 'PREV';
    protected $lastLink       = 'Last';
    protected $fullTagOpen    = '<div class="pagination">';
    protected $fullTagClose   = '</div>';
    protected $firstTagOpen   = '';
    protected $firstTagClose  = '&nbsp;';
    protected $lastTagOpen    = '&nbsp;';
    protected $lastTagClose    = '';
    protected $curTagOpen    = '&nbsp;<span style="background-color:#ce1b0a;color:#ced2db;font-weight:bolder;padding:5px;">';
    protected $curTagClose    = '</span></b>';
    protected $nextTagOpen    = '&nbsp;';
    protected $nextTagClose    = '&nbsp;';
    protected $prevTagOpen    = '&nbsp;';
    protected $prevTagClose    = '';
    protected $numTagOpen    = '&nbsp;';
    protected $numTagClose    = '';
    protected $showCount    = true;
    protected $currentOffset= 0;
    protected $queryStringSegment = 'page';
    
    function __construct($params = array()){
        if (count($params) > 0){
            $this->initialize($params);        
        }
    }
    
    function initialize($params = array()){
        if (count($params) > 0){
            foreach ($params as $key => $val){
                if (isset($this->$key)){
                    $this->$key = $val;
                }
            }        
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Generate the pagination links
     */    
    function createLinks(){ 
        // If total number of rows is zero, do not need to continue
        if ($this->totalRows == 0 OR $this->perPage == 0){
           return '';
        }
        // Calculate the total number of pages
        $numPages = ceil($this->totalRows / $this->perPage);
        // Is there only one page? will not need to continue
        if ($numPages == 1){
            if ($this->showCount){
                $info = 'Showing : ' . $this->totalRows;
                return $info;
            }else{
                return '';
            }
        }
        
        // Determine query string
        $query_string_sep = (strpos($this->baseURL, '?') === FALSE) ? '?page=' : '&amp;page=';
        $this->baseURL = $this->baseURL.$query_string_sep;
        
        // Determine the current page
        $this->currentPage = isset($_GET[$this->queryStringSegment])?$_GET[$this->queryStringSegment]:0;
        
        if (!is_numeric($this->currentPage) || $this->currentPage == 0){
            $this->currentPage = 1;
        }
        
        // Links content string variable
        $output = '';
        
        // Showing links notification
        if ($this->showCount){
           $currentOffset = ($this->currentPage > 1)?($this->currentPage - 1)*$this->perPage:$this->currentPage;
           $info = 'Showing ' . $currentOffset . ' to ' ;
        
           if( ($currentOffset + $this->perPage) <= $this->totalRows )
              $info .= $this->currentPage * $this->perPage;
           else
              $info .= $this->totalRows;
        
           $info .= ' of ' . $this->totalRows . ' | ';
        
           $output .= $info;
        }
        
        $this->numLinks = (int)$this->numLinks;
        
        // Is the page number beyond the result range? the last page will show
        if($this->currentPage > $this->totalRows){
            $this->currentPage = $numPages;
        }
        
        $uriPageNum = $this->currentPage;
        
        // Calculate the start and end numbers. 
        $start = (($this->currentPage - $this->numLinks) > 0) ? $this->currentPage - ($this->numLinks - 1) : 1;
        $end   = (($this->currentPage + $this->numLinks) < $numPages) ? $this->currentPage + $this->numLinks : $numPages;
        
        // Render the "First" link
        if($this->currentPage > $this->numLinks){
            $firstPageURL = str_replace($query_string_sep,'',$this->baseURL);
            $output .= $this->firstTagOpen.'<a style="background-color:white;padding:5px;border-radius:3px;text-decoration:none;" href="'.$firstPageURL.'">'.$this->firstLink.'</a>'.$this->firstTagClose;
        }
        // Render the "previous" link
        if($this->currentPage != 1){
            $i = ($uriPageNum - 1);
            if($i == 0) $i = '';
            $output .= $this->prevTagOpen.'<a style="background-color:white;padding:5px;border-radius:3px;text-decoration:none;" href="'.$this->baseURL.$i.'">'.$this->prevLink.'</a>'.$this->prevTagClose;
        }
        // Write the digit links
        for($loop = $start -1; $loop <= $end; $loop++){
            $i = $loop;
            if($i >= 1){
                if($this->currentPage == $loop){
                    $output .= $this->curTagOpen.$loop.$this->curTagClose;
                }else{
                    $output .= $this->numTagOpen.'<a style="background-color:white;padding:5px;border-radius:3px;text-decoration:none;" href="'.$this->baseURL.$i.'">'.$loop.'</a>'.$this->numTagClose;
                }
            }
        }
        // Render the "next" link
        if($this->currentPage < $numPages){
            $i = ($this->currentPage + 1);
            $output .= $this->nextTagOpen.'<a style="background-color:white;padding:5px;border-radius:3px;text-decoration:none;" href="'.$this->baseURL.$i.'">'.$this->nextLink.'</a>'.$this->nextTagClose;
        }
        // Render the "Last" link
        if(($this->currentPage + $this->numLinks) < $numPages){
            $i = $numPages;
            $output .= $this->lastTagOpen.'<a style="background-color:white;padding:5px;border-radius:3px;text-decoration:none;" href="'.$this->baseURL.$i.'">'.$this->lastLink.'</a>'.$this->lastTagClose;
        }
        // Remove double slashes
        $output = preg_replace("#([^:])//+#", "\\1/", $output);
        // Add the wrapper HTML if exists
        $output = $this->fullTagOpen.$output.$this->fullTagClose;
        
        return $output;        
    }
}
```

I change the variable to an integer and it works fine.  The user needs to have the option to select how many records per page to display.  If he/she selects 25, that number should be displayed on all pages.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? That's a lot of code for others to check

Comment: Does every page have `$_REQUEST['npp'];`? Set a session maybe when the number of items is changed by the user

Comment: If I enter an integer value, all pages work with that same number per page.  With the dropdown, you have to specify a number on each page after clicking on that page number.  So, if I select 10 on the 1st page, 10 records are displayed on that page.  If I click on 25 records on the next page, 25 records are displayed.  I truly don't know how to make the number - let's say 10 - stay in "memory" so the user doesn't have to keep selecting the number on every page.

Comment: Can you remove all the code that is _not_ related to the issue at hand? Dumping a bunch of unnecessary code just makes it harder for us to get a proper picture, which is the opposite of what you want when asking for help.

Comment: "_I truly don't know how to make the number - let's say 10 - stay in "memory"_" Store it in a session? Store it in a database? In a file? Attach it to every request?

Comment: Do you think storing that number in a session might be the best option?

Comment: I created a session variable and assigned that to the $perPageLimit varialbe and it still makes me choose a number on all other pages.  I'm going to try to "Attach it to every request."

Comment: No, storing this into the session is not a good idea. If I was paginating two different results sets in two different browser tabs, the session value would be overwritten as soon as I make a choice in one of them. Plus, your pagination links would not be bookmarkable / shareable any more - if I shared a link for "page 15" with you, then what we would both see, would totally depend on the current perPageLimit, which could be different for you than it is for me.

Comment: Understood, @CBroe.  I tried creating a session and it did not work.

Comment: As noted, a very common pattern is to just always include the variable's value in every request, and you can set the "selected" property on the dropdown menu: https://3v4l.org/MnCKm

Answer (score -2):

If this helps anyone, I figured it out.  1) I created a field in my users table called show_leads.  Then, I created a select option drop down menu in the users window where the user could select the number of records to display.

Lastly, starting with "$query2," the code to select the number and retrieving the records is how I now have this all working:

```
<?php

// Start session
session_start();

include_once 'config/dbconfig.php';


// Get session data
$sessData = !empty($_SESSION['sessData'])?$_SESSION['sessData']:'';

// Get status message from session
if(!empty($sessData['status']['msg'])){
    $statusMsg = $sessData['status']['msg'];
    $statusMsgType = $sessData['status']['type'];
    unset($_SESSION['sessData']['status']);
}

// Load pagination class
require_once 'Pagination.class.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["username"]); ?>'s Leads | CRM</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script>
    cPrev = -1; // global var saves the previous c, used to
            // determine if the same column is clicked again

function sortBy(c) {
    rows = document.getElementById("sortable").rows.length; // num of rows
    columns = document.getElementById("sortable").rows[0].cells.length; // num of columns
    arrTable = [...Array(rows)].map(e => Array(columns)); // create an empty 2d array

    for (ro=0; ro<rows; ro++) { // cycle through rows
        for (co=0; co<columns; co++) { // cycle through columns
            // assign the value in each row-column to a 2d array by row-column
            arrTable[ro][co] = document.getElementById("sortable").rows[ro].cells[co].innerHTML;
        }
    }

    th = arrTable.shift(); // remove the header row from the array, and save it
    
    if (c !== cPrev) { // different column is clicked, so sort by the new column
        arrTable.sort(
            function (a, b) {
                if (a[c] === b[c]) {
                    return 0;
                } else {
                    return (a[c] < b[c]) ? -1 : 1;
                }
            }
        );
    } else { // if the same column is clicked then reverse the array
        arrTable.reverse();
    }
    
    cPrev = c; // save in previous c

    arrTable.unshift(th); // put the header back in to the array

    // cycle through rows-columns placing values from the array back into the html table
    for (ro=0; ro<rows; ro++) {
        for (co=0; co<columns; co++) {
            document.getElementById("sortable").rows[ro].cells[co].innerHTML = arrTable[ro][co];
        }
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body class="a2z-wrapper" cz-shortcut-listen="true" style="width:90%;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;background-color:#9dc7f1;">
<!-- <div class="loggedintime" style="width:150px;height:50px;background-color:#f1bb7a;float:left;font-size:2.0em;text-align:center"> -->
<!-- </div> -->
<?php
include './header2.php';
?>
<?php

// Load and initialize database class
require_once 'DBml.class.php';
$db = new DB();

***$query2=" SELECT ml_show_leads FROM wpbestp_home_purchase WHERE assigned_to = '".$_SESSION['username']."'";
foreach ($db_con->query($query2) as $row) {
}
?>
<input type="text" style="background-color:#fff;width:30px;border:2px solid red;font-size:1.3em;" name="ml_show_leads" value="<?php echo $row['ml_show_leads']; ?>">***<br>
<?php
$show_records = $row['ml_show_leads'];

$perPageLimit = $show_records;

// echo $_POST['npp'];
$offset = !empty($_GET['page'])?(($_GET['page']-1)*$perPageLimit):0;



// Get count of the prospects
$con = array(
    'like_or' => $searchArr,
    'return_type' => 'count'
);
$rowCount = $db->getRows('wpbestp_home_purchase', $con);


// Initialize pagination class
$pagConfig = array(
    'baseURL' => 'myleads.php'.$searchStr,
    'totalRows' => $rowCount,
    'perPage' => $perPageLimit
);
$pagination = new Pagination($pagConfig);

// Get leads from database
$con = array(
    'like_or' => $searchArr,
    'start' => $offset,
    'limit' => $perPageLimit,
    'order_by' => 'id DESC',
);
$prospects = $db->getRows('wpbestp_home_purchase', $con);
// Export search results to CSV
?>
<!-- <div class="float-left" style="padding-top:5px;">
        <a href="exportData.php" class="btn btn-success"><i class="dwn"></i> Export Search Results to CSV</a>
    </div> -->

<!-- Display status message -->
<?php if(!empty($statusMsg) && ($statusMsgType == 'success')){ ?>
<div class="alert alert-success" style="font-size:1.5em;"><?php echo $statusMsg; ?></div>
<?php }elseif(!empty($statusMsg) && ($statusMsgType == 'error')){ ?>
<div class="alert alert-danger" style="font-size:1.5em;"><?php echo $statusMsg; ?></div>
<?php } ?>
 
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 search-panel">
        <!-- Search form -->
        <form>
        <div class="input-group" style="float:right;">
        <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for leads..">
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Data list table --> 
    <table cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="sortable" class="table table-striped table-hover table-responsive" style="margin-left:-30px;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th onclick="sortBy(0)">ID&nbsp;&#x2B0D;</th>
                <th onclick="sortBy(1)">Trans Type&nbsp;&#x2B0D;</th>
                <th onclick="sortBy(2)">Entered&nbsp;&#x2B0D;</th>
                <th onclick="sortBy(3)">FName&nbsp;&#x2B0D;</th>
                <th onclick="sortBy(4)">LName&nbsp;&#x2B0D;</th>
                <th onclick="sortBy(5)">Loan Amount&nbsp;&#x2B0D;</th>
                <th onclick="sortBy(6)">Sales Price&nbsp;&#x2B0D;</th>
                <th onclick="sortBy(7)">LTV&nbsp;&#x2B0D;</th>
                <th onclick="sortBy(8)">Email&nbsp;&#x2B0D;</th>
                <th onclick="sortBy(9)">Phone&nbsp;&#x2B0D;</th>
                <th onclick="sortBy(10)">Dup Phone&nbsp;&#x2B0D;</th>
                <th onclick="sortBy(11)">Prop Address&nbsp;&#x2B0D;</th>
                <th onclick="sortBy(12)">Prop City&nbsp;&#x2B0D;</th>
                <th onclick="sortBy(13)">Prop State&nbsp;&#x2B0D;</th>
                <th onclick="sortBy(14)">Prop Zip&nbsp;&#x2B0D;</th>
                <th onclick="sortBy(15)">Assigned&nbsp;&#x2B0D;</th>
                <th onclick="sortBy(16)">Prospect Msg&nbsp;&#x2B0D;</th>
                <th onclick="sortBy(17)">Status&nbsp;&#x2B0D;</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
            if(!empty($prospects)){ $count = 0; 
                foreach($prospects as $prospect){ $count++;
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $prospect['id']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $prospect['transaction_type']; ?></td>
                <td><?php 
                if ($prospect['time_ago_second'] > "0" AND $prospect['time_ago_second'] < "180") {
                    echo $prospect['time_ago_second'], " seconds ago";
                } else if ($prospect['time_ago_second'] > "180" AND $prospect['time_ago_second'] < "3600") {
                    echo $prospect['time_ago_minute'], " minutes ago";
                } else if ($prospect['time_ago_minute'] > "59" AND $prospect['time_ago_minute'] < "120") {
                    echo "Over ", $prospect['time_ago_hour'], " hour ago";
                } else if ($prospect['time_ago_minute'] > "120" AND $prospect['time_ago_minute'] < "1400") {
                    echo "Over ", $prospect['time_ago_hour'], " hours ago";
                } else if ($prospect['time_ago_hour'] > "24" AND $prospect['time_ago_hour'] < "48") {
                    echo "Over ", $prospect['time_ago_day'], " day ago";
                } else if ($prospect['time_ago_hour'] > "24") {
                    echo "Over ", $prospect['time_ago_day'], " days ago";
                } else ''
                ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $prospect['fName']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $prospect['lName']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo number_format($prospect['loan_amount']); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo number_format($prospect['salesprice']); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo number_format((float)($prospect[loan_amount]/$prospect[salesprice])*100,2,'.',''); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $prospect['pemail']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo '(' .substr($prospect['primary_phone'],0,3) . ') ' . substr($prospect['primary_phone'], 3,3) . '-' . substr($prospect['primary_phone'], 6,4); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $prospect['dupphonenum']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $prospect['property_street']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $prospect['property_city']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $prospect['property_state']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $prospect['property_zipcode']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $prospect['assigned_to']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $prospect['user_message']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $prospect['lead_status']; ?></td>
                <td>
                    <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" style="font-size:1.4em;" href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $prospect['id']; ?>" id="cb" style="pointer-events: none;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit">
                    <!-- <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" style="font-size:1.4em;" href="leadstatuschanges.php?id=<?php echo $prospect['id']; ?>" id="cb" style="pointer-events: none;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Lead Status Changes"> -->
                    
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php } }else{ ?>
            <tr><td colspan="5" style="font-size:1.4em;">No lead(s) found......</td></tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br>
    <!-- Display pagination links --> 
    <?php echo $pagination->createLinks(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Please keep in mind that your SQL query is still highly vulnerable for SQL injection. Any username containing a single quote breaks the query, and I hope you don't use this code in any production environment